# Database is not accessible after 'taking it offline' process failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was trying to detach the DB when it gave me an error that it is currently in use. Hence, I tried to take my DB offline but it failed saying

```
'an exception occured while executing a transact SQL statement or batch 

-> ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'myDB'. Try again later.
    ALTER DATABASE statement failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5061)'
```

Now if I try and access the DB it says it is not accessible. What can I do to make my DB accessible again?

My aim was to detach the DB, relocate its secondary database file to a new drive and reattach it (simply because of space issues).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try following steps.

1. Restart the SQL server service using `services.msc` console.
2. Now connect to your server using SQL Server Management Studio.
3. Run following command in query analyzer

   ```
     ALTER DATABASE `YOURDATABASE_NAME`  
     SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
   ```
4. Now Right-click the database name, point to Tasks, and then click Detach. The Detach Database dialog box appears

OR 
5. Run your command to Relocate the secondary database.

1. Set the database mode to multi user again

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE `YOURDATABASE_NAME` SET MULTI_USER
   ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative to step one in Furqan's answer, you might not need to restart the SQL Server instance, but only the SQL Server Management Studio instance, which was used to initiate the "Take Offline" task.

Comment: Thanks for this - meant we didn't have to take the whole SQL Server offline!

Comment: I can confirm this to be true. The Management Studio seems to be keeping a connection open.

Comment: Sorry but unable to login to that instance.

Comment: I also had to stop the IIS website that was connected to the database. From https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138031/55073, it seems to need getting all users off, so sometimes restart needed, sometimes just quitting SSMS, in my case also stopping IIS.